# Probing USB LTE Modem - ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc. - Chip: Qualcomm 9600

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, usb-modem, modem

I purchased this Dongle from Aliexpress: [enter link description here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4G-LTE-Wireless-USB-Dongle-Mobile-Broadband-150Mbps-Modem-Stick-Sim-Card-Wireless-Router-USB-150Mbps/1005003707568410.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.67674c4d9aUxyi)

Chip: Qualcomm 9600

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS on x86_64 cpu
After I plug it it I got:

```
    ~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 De    ~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc.vice 011: ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc.
```

```
    :~$ sudo lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 11, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 11, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
```

```
    ~$sudo dmesg -t
rndis_host 2-1.1:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, RNDIS device
usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=902d
usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 2-1.1: Product: Android
usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Android
usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 0
rndis_host 2-1.1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, RNDIS device, 52:c5:16:b3:68:97
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): usb0: link is not ready
usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 9
rndis_host 2-1.1:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, RNDIS device
usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=d002
usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 2-1.1: Product: Android
usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Android
usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 0
usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 10
usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=9024
usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 2-1.1: Product: Android
usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Android
usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 0
rndis_host 2-1.1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, RNDIS device, 92:5a:3d:66:56:0d
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): usb0: link is not ready
```

```
    ~$ ip a
11: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:5a:3d:66:56:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.42.151/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 2752sec preferred_lft 2752sec
    inet6 fe80::cdce:6fbd:4ffa:6d2e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

From web browser I can connect to 192.168.100.1 and open the dashboard panel where I can set up my broadband connection (APN etc).
But I have no connection to Interntet.

So, from here I started to read and investigate on how to probe this device in order to make it works.

I read a lot about how to send AT commands to modems, but I have no success with it.
I can't understand if it is related to the drivers/modules that are loaded:

```
    # sudo lsusb -vvv

Bus 002 Device 010: ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x05c6 Qualcomm, Inc.
  idProduct          0x9024 
  bcdDevice            3.10
  iManufacturer           1 Android
  iProduct                2 Android
  iSerial                 3 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           98
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass        224 Wireless
      bFunctionSubClass       1 Radio Frequency
      bFunctionProtocol       3 RNDIS
      iFunction               7 RNDIS
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      3 RNDIS
      iInterface              5 RNDIS Communications Control
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 00 10 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 01 00 01
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  04 24 02 00
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 06 00 01
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               9
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              6 RNDIS Ethernet Data
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass     66 
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              4 ADB Interface
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

I tried to bind to usbserial driver

```
    modprobe usbserial vendor=0x05c6 product=0x9024
```

and on If 2 of the device I got:

```
    # sudo lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbserial_generic, 480M
```

Also /dev/ttyUSB0 got created.

But I can't access it or send it any AT commands.

I used minicom 2.7.1, and I got this message after I tried some features:

`Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0!`

So, my question: How can I probe/set this device?

Thanks

Comment: Is your user in the group dialout?

Comment: I think you're going at it the wrong way. Your device is supposed to work like any other "MiFi" albeit having the "old" USB modem form factor. It provides a USB Ethernet connection and if can access it's IP and manage it then it's completely fine from the OS POV. That it doesn't connect after the setup means the setup is wrong or some incompatibility with the ISP or something else. Now, it *may* work (or may not) as a regular modem as well - in which case it would make sense to use AT commands - but first it would have to be switched to that mode, the default being USB Ethernet. (...)

Comment: (...) Because it also has a WiFi component it's highly unlikely it work is any other mode. It's designed to be configured at its home page, period. Once configured it can even work (via WiFi) simply connected to any 5V changer, it's a self-contained router and doesn't require a computer. So, check your settings and your service. Keep in mind some APNs require additional parameters, without the exact settings there's no internet access.

Comment: @nobody yes it is

Comment: @ChanganAuto ok, I want to do it as I need to find what it's the problem that doesn't allow me to connect through Internet